# Collections sort doesnt work to me

Tags: java, collections

I tried to use Collections.sort and it is working until I want it to sort between double variables

price is the double variable...

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Product p) {
    double lastCmp = this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice());
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice()));
}

  public void OrganizeByLowestPrice(Basket basket) {
    ArrayList<Product> products1 = basket.getBasket();
    Collections.sort(products1, new Comparator<Product>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product product, Product t1) {
            return product.getPrice().compareTo(t1.getPrice());
        }
    });
}
```

https://pastebin.com/6VxhzSRG

I added the code for Product. 
problem stays the same.
It once worked for me but now as I am recovering lost codes its not.

Comment: Why are you caching the previous result of `compareTo`? That's wrong.

Comment: do you understand why this: double lastCmp = this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice());
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice()));
is nonsense?

Comment: why are you comparing the same price twice?

Comment: Show us the `Product` class.

Comment: If you simply want to sort in ascending order consider using `Comparator.naturalOrder()` on the values of `getPrice` over a (seemingly non-functional) own implementation.

Comment: It's confusing. Are you showing us two different sorts and one of them is working? If this is so, which one is working and which one isn't?

Comment: What is the return type of `getPrice`?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala he states that price is a double variable, so just assume it's a Double

Comment: @Stultuske then it should be working.

Comment: the first function is the function used in the main. 
I get the problem only when I am trying to compare between doubles. 
It is the same code just different parameters.... 

Added the Product's code

Answer (score 1):

So the real problem here is compilation errors.  The germane ones are these:

```
Product.java:51: error: double cannot be dereferenced
    double lastCmp = this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice());
                               ^
Product.java:52: error: double cannot be dereferenced
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice()));
                                               ^
Product.java:52: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice()));
                         ^
```

These are straight forward:

- The first error occurs because you are trying to invoke a method (`compareTo`) on a `double`.  That is not valid Java. Primitive types don't have methods.
- The second error occurs for the same reason as the first
- The final error occurs because `(lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : this.price.compareTo(p.getPrice()))` produces a `double`, but the 
  `Product::compareTo` method must return an `int`.  So the `return` statement is *attempting* convert the `double` to an `int`.  But a conversion from `double` to `int` is lossy, and the Java language requires an explicit type cast to do that.

Solution:

1. The `lastCmp` variable should not be a `double`.  It should be an `int`.
2. If you want to compare two `double` values, use the static `Double::compare` method; e.g.

   ```
     int lastCmp = Double.compare(this.price, p.getPrice());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda simply.

```
public void OrganizeByLowestPrice(Basket basket) {
    ArrayList<Product> products1 = basket.getBasket();
    Collections.sort(products1, (a,b)->{
        return Double.compare(b.getPrice(),a.getPrice());
    });
}
```

It sorts the list in decreasing order on the basis of price.

Comment: normally, his current code should be sorting as well